# datagrid is sort on edit the cell with binding source list<Student>

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

when user edit a cell value in the event dataGridViewStudents_CellValueChanged. Data grid values are sort accordingly.

```
 private void form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {
            List<student> lststudent=new List<student>(); 
             lststudent.add("1","Abc", 26);
             lststudent.add("1","xyz", 31);
             lststudent.add("1","pqr", 53);
             lststudent.add("1", "def", 23);
            DataGridView.DataSource= lststudent; 
        }
        private void datagridStudent_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewCell cell = null;
            if (e.RowIndex > -1 && e.ColumnIndex > -1)
            {
                cell = ((DataGridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

                ((DataGridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value = 36; ((DataGridView)sender).Sort(((DataGridView)sender).Columns["marks"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
            }
        }
```

In this code when user edit a cell in datagrid. it does not sort the datagrid according to that column. datagrid is bind with list. so, i want to sort the datagrid when user change cell value.

Comment: I think you forgot the question :)

Comment: In this code when user edit a cell in datagrid. it does not sort the datagrid according to that column. datagrid is bind with list. so, i want to sort the datagrid when user change cell value.

Comment: See [this][1] question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672984/why-wont-my-column-sort-in-a-winforms-net-datagrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private void datagridStudent_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var t = ((List<Student>)DataGridView.DataSource).OrderBy(x=>x.Marks).ToList();
        //or var t =((List<Student>)DataGridView.DataSource).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Marks).ToList();
        DataGridView.DataSource = t;
    }
```

Comment: last line give error "Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function."

Comment: should i use SortableBindingList?

Comment: you can use SortableBindingList. i tested code again there wasnt an error.